# ng-value com 2 valores e 2 ng-model no mesmo input-radio

Tags: angularjs, ionic

No `ion-radio` tem o `ng-value` com 2 valores. O `ng-model` está pegando o valor do `ng-value`. O problema aqui é que eu quero exibir esses 2 valores do `ng-value` separado.

ex: `{{data.nomeOpc}}` exibe nome da opção, e `{{data.valorOpc}}` exibe o valor da opção. Neste model ele exibe os 2 juntos e eu quero separar os valores. Agradeço a ajuda

```
     <ion-list>
        <h3>Opções</h3>
        <ion-radio ng-repeat = "child in produto.opcoes" value = "{{child}}" ng-change = "pegar(data)" ng-model = "data.opcoes">
           <strong>{{child.nomeOpc}}
              <span> = {{child.valorOpc | currency: 'R$'}}</span>
           </strong>
        </ion-radio>
     </ion-list>
```

Segue abaixo a função no controller

```
$scope.pegar = function(data) {
 $scope.data = JSON.parse(data.opcoes);
  console.log($scope.data)
  console.log($scope.data.id, $scope.data.nomeOpc);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por quê você não passa o objeto inteiro no value e depois manipula ele no controller? Seria mais ou menos isso em AngularJs:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dados = [{
        id: 1,
        nome: 'Diego'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        nome: 'Fernando'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        nome: 'Bruno'
    }];
  
    $scope.pegar = function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.id, data.nome);
   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="item in dados">
            <label>{{item.nome}}
                <input type="radio" ng-model="data.nome" name="name" 
                value="{{item}}" ng-change="pegar(item)" />
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

OBS: Para visualizar o resultado entre no modo desenvolvedor do navegador e vá no console.

---

Atualização:

No seu `ng-change` ao invés de passar o conteúdo do `ng-model` passe o conteúdo do `value`:

```
<ion-radio ng-repeat = "child in dados" value = "{{child}}"  ng-model = "data.nome" ng-change = "pegar(child)"  ng-checked="true">
```

E então na sua função `pegar`:

```
$scope.pegar = function(data) {
     //$scope.data = data;
     console.log(data)
     console.log(data.id, data.nome);
}
```

Exemplo com Ionic: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNYOgK

Comment: opa...deu certo aqui..ele retornou como o seu exemplo. Agora como faço pra separar esses valores em $scope separado.  Quando clico em uma opção no console ele retorna: Object {idOpc: "66", nomeOpc: "01 pessoa", valorOpc: "26.50"}

Comment: ex: `$scope.item.idOpc`, `$scope.item.nomeOpc`

Comment: Editei o exemplo que postei, de uma olhada.

Comment: cara...deu certo tbm o exemplo q vc me passou. Eles separaram por scope. Mais agora da dando um erro q eu acho besta, mais não sei. Quando mudei para o ultimo código q vc me passou, o simbolo de checked do radio não aparece mais. Ele pega o valor mais não aparece mais o simbolo de checked.

Comment: Eu atualizei o código de acordo com o que você passou. @Techies

Comment: @AlexandreScrideli Editei a resposta e adicionei um exemplo funcionando com Ionic

Comment: Eu montei uma estrutura no codepen, com os 2 exemplos q vc me passou. O ultimo exemplo resolve o problema do bug do checked, mais não da pra mostrar qual opção setada em um escopo. Aqui segue o link do codepen. http://codepen.io/alexandre_developer/pen/JXPwdd?editors=1011 @Techies

Comment: Da pra mostra no escopo sim, é só você atribuir a variável data a um $scope

Comment: @AlexandreScrideli Editei a resposta, de uma olhada no link do codepen

Comment: Obs: No codigo do botão use ng-click ao invés de ng-change

Comment: Brother desculpa a demora da resposta. Seu código me ajudou bastante e consegui entender muita coisa aqui, só de ler o seu código....valeu pela ajuda mesmo. @Techies

Comment: @AlexandreScrideli deu certo?

Comment: Deu sim @Techies. Com o seu código, aprendi várias coisas q não sabia. Você me ajudou pakas meu. Valeu mesmo

Comment: eu abri uma nova pergunta aqui, se vc puder me ajudar, agradeceria muito meu. O link é http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116194/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-get-no-service-js-retorna-null?noredirect=1#comment242386_116194

Comment: Opa, que bom que deu certo @AlexandreScrideli, continue programando e boa sorte. Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como correta pra ela ajudar outros usuários com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Eu sei q é um erro besta pakas, mais não manjo muito de programação. Eu sou mais lnguagem de marcação, então to aprendendo aos poucos.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada nela

Comment: Valeu mesmo brother...