# Função Get no service.js retorna null

Tags: angularjs, json

Tenho um Json de categorias com um array de produtos dentro dele. Buscar todas as categorias e todos os produtos de acordo com a categoria, está buscando. Agora o problema é que eu quero retornar o detalhe do produto pelo id do produto, mas no console está retornando `null`.

**Json**

```
.factory('Categorias', function() {

 var categorias = [
 {//Nova Categoria
    "idCategoria": 1,
    "nomeCategoria": "categoria 1",
    "produtos": [
       {//Novo Produto
          "idProduto": 1,
          "nomeProduto": "produto 01A",
       },
       {//Novo Produto
          "idProduto": 2,
          "nomeProduto": "produto 02A",
       }
    ]
 }
];

return {
all: function() {
  return categorias;
},
get: function(categoriaId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++) {
    if (categorias[i].idCategoria === parseInt(categoriaId)) {
      return categorias[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
},
 getProduto: function(produtoId) {
 for (var i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++) {
  if (categorias[i].idProduto === parseInt(produtoId)) {
     return categorias[i];
  }
 }
 return null;
}
};
});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ProdutoDetalheCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Categorias) {
  $scope.produtosCategoria = Categorias.getProduto($stateParams.produtoId)
  console.log($stateParams.produtoId);
  console.log($scope.produtosCategoria)
})
```

**Console**

```
1
null
```

Comment: A function `getProduto` não me parece estar correta...

Comment: isso eu sei, é ai q eu to com problema...como q eu faço pra entrar dentro do array produtos no getProduto. Ta retornando null pq não ta achando os produtos

Comment: Poxa, você poderia ter explicado isso na pergunta. Está parecendo que você não faz ideia de onde está o erro...

Comment: Eu sei q o erro ta ai, mais não sei como montar essa function q retorna o produto pelo idProduto

Comment: A variável `categorias` é pra ser o seu Json?

Comment: isso mesmo. é um json só. Quero buscar no function getProduto o produto dentro da categoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como já responderam você precisa de dois `For's` um pra percorrer categorias e outro pra percorrer os produtos.

Como alternativa você pode utilizar o `angular.ForEach()` pra percorrer seus`arrays`:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Categorias', function() {
  
    var categorias = [{
        "idCategoria": 1,
        "nomeCategoria": "categoria 1",
        "produtos": [{ 
            "idProduto": 1,
            "nomeProduto": "produto 01A",
        }, { 
            "idProduto": 2,
            "nomeProduto": "produto 02A",
        }]
    }];

    return {
   
        getProduto: function(produtoId) {
            var produto = {};
            angular.forEach(categorias, function(categoriaCorrente) {
                angular.forEach(categoriaCorrente.produtos, function(produtoCorrente) {
                    if (produtoCorrente.idProduto === parseInt(produtoId)) {
                        produto = produtoCorrente;
                    }
                })
            })
            return produto;
        }
    };

});

function MyCtrl($scope, Categorias) {
    $scope.produtosCategoria = Categorias.getProduto(1)
    console.log(1);
    console.log($scope.produtosCategoria)
    console.log("ID: ",$scope.produtosCategoria.idProduto)
    console.log("Nome: ",$scope.produtosCategoria.nomeProduto)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
ID Produto: <b>{{produtosCategoria.idProduto}}</b>
 </br>
Nome Produto: <b>{{produtosCategoria.nomeProduto}}</b>
</div>
```

Se preferir pode utilziar o [forEach do EcmaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),
Exemplo:

```
 lista.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item)
  })
```

Comment: Bem lembrado. Ele não pode aplicar o `forEach` direto no objeto `categorias`? Tipo, `categorias.forEach(...)`?

Comment: Não sei se tem como fazer dessa forma, pois na documentação do Angular está como fiz rs. Só se tiver como fazer utilizando JS nativo

Comment: @jbueno acabei de fazer um teste e com ECM da pra fazer :p

Comment: Eu estava testando aqui também, realmente dá certo

Comment: Deu certo tbm o seu código @Techies. Mais um conhecimento q vou guardar aqui, pra estudar. Valeu pela força. abraços

Answer (score 1):

O "categorias[i].idProduto" que você usa para comparar com o "produtoId" não existe. O que existe é o "categorias[i].produtos[y].idProduto".

Então sua função tinha que ser algo assim:

```
for (var i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++) {
   for (var y = 0; i < categorias[i].produtos.length; y++) {
      if (categorias[i].produtos[y].idProduto === produtoId) {
          return categorias[i].produtos[y];
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Valeu pela força tbm@AlexandreBusarello. Peguei o seu código tbm, mais reparei q tinha 2 erros. faltava uma chave e o parseInt. Mais valeu pela força tbm.

Comment: Corrigido a falta das chaves e o parseInt que faltava. Escrevi aqui rapidão e acabei não me atendo. Obrigado.

Comment: tranquilo. Valeu pela força mais uma vez

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo sua lógica, a função `getProduto` deveria estar assim

```
getProduto: function(produtoId) {
 for (var i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++){
     for(var c = 0; c < categorias[i].produtos.length; c++){  
         if (categorias[i].produtos[c].idProduto === parseInt(produtoId)) {
             return categorias[i].produtos[c];
         }
     }
 }
 return null;
}
```

Comment: Deu certo aqui @jbueno. Conseguiu mostrar a página de detalhe do produto. Oq tava errado no json, era q os produtos, mesmo em outra categoria, não pode ter o mesmo id. Seria isso?

Comment: agora entendi, qual seria minha duvida @jbueno. Não sabia fazer 2 for, valeu mesmo pelas informações. abraços